# Propositional logic involving negation and if-statement: precedence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Quick help:

So this is confusing me for some reason. I don't know what rule am i missing. I feel both should equal the same no matter how you start it.

-(p → q)

= (-p → -q)

= (p ∨ -q)

or

-(p → q)

= -((-p) ∨ q)

= (p ∧ -q)

Which one is valid? and why? what rule am i missing?

Comment: Assuming "-" means $\neg$ (\neg surrounded by \$ signs), the second is valid, the first is nuts. // If "they both should equal the same", then $p \vee \neg q$ would mean the same thing as $p \wedge \neg q$, for any $p, q$... so $p \vee q$ would mean the same thing as, and be equivalent to, $p \wedge q$, for any $p, q$. That's wrong, right?

Comment: ok i get that thanks but why we don't start with the negation first? is there a rule that says start with the if-statement first then negate?

Comment: Suppose that p is false and q is false.  Then -(p → q) is false, while (-p → -q) is true.  Thus, [-(p → q) = (-p → -q)] for all values of p and q.  On the other hand for all values of p and q, [-(p → q) = -((-p) ∨ q)] is true.

Comment: "Thus, [-(p → q) = (-p → -q)] for all values of p and q."

That should read "Thus, it is not the case that [-(p → q) = (-p → -q)] for all values of p and q."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no prescribed order for the application of rules when you want to  establish an equivalence between two propositional formulas. Here are some valid equivalences that apply to the formulas you're dealing with. I'll change the variable names so you can more easily swap in your subformulas:

$$
\begin{align}
\neg\,(A\to B) &\iff (A \wedge \neg B) \\
(A\to B) &\iff (\neg A \vee B) \\
\neg\,(A\wedge B) &\iff \neg A \vee \neg B \\
 \neg \neg\, C &\iff C \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I still don't see why this is not possible: -(p → q) = (-p → -q), then go from there. I think i need sleep.

Comment: $\neg(p\to q) \iff \neg p \vee q$, which is true except when $p$ is true and $q$ is false. $\neg p \to \neg q \iff p \vee \neg q$ is true except when $p$ is false and $q$ is true. They're not the same. Really.

Comment: Thanks. I see it much better now. Needed some sleep lol.